# What happens when we divide a 16-bit number with a 8-bit 1?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm, integer-division

As far as I have heard, if we use div instruction with a 8-bit number then the quotient is a 8-bit number stored in AL and the remainder is again a 8-bit number stored in AH

But what if we divide a 16-bit number by 1?

I ended up having my instruction pointer getting misplaced whenever the below code is executed.

```
MOV AX, 9999H
MOV BL, 1
DIV BL
```

Is there any way we can force 8086 to use ax for quotient and do for remainder while dividing by AX?

Comment: @SepRoland: it can't be both TASM and EMU8086.  Use `[x86-16]` for 16-bit code, including 8086.  Question text can handle that for the few cases where there's a big difference between an 8086 vs. a 286 answer.  (`[8086]` is a tag-synonym for [x86-16], which is fine, despite tag auto-completion of 8086 to emu8086).  emu8086 is one specific assembler + simulator + debugger and isn't really good for questions about the ISA.

Comment: @PeterCordes I wasn't aware of that. Anyway there are at least 12 question tagged with both TASM and EMU8086.

Comment: @SepRoland: If it's about asm syntax, then TASM and emu8086 do use similar MASM-like syntax so they might not all need to get retagged.  And maybe not worth bothering with on existing old questions.

Answer (score 5):

*On the 8086 processor you can choose between a byte-sized division and a word-sized division.*

---

The **byte**-sized division will divide the word in `AX` by whichever **byte**-sized operand you specify. Your example code uses this kind of division. The quotient goes to the `AL` register and the remainder goes to the `AH` register.

In your example dividing 9999h by 1 yields a quotient of 9999h. This result is too big to fit in `AL` and therefore you got a #DE division exception.

The **word**-sized division will divide the doubleword in `DX:AX` by whichever **word**-sized operand you specify. The quotient goes to the `AX` register and the remainder goes to the `DX` register.

Your example:

```
XOR DX, DX
MOV AX, 9999H
MOV BX, 1
DIV BX
```

This time there's no problem and the `AX` register will hold the quotient 9999h and the `DX` register will hold the remainder 0.

**EDIT after comment**

> I'm sorry to be unclear...What I am actually trying to do is divide a 8 bit register by a 16-bit register in order to obtain a 16-bit quotient...i dont need the remainder

An example would then be `BL` / `CX` producing `AX`

If that is what you want to do, then be aware that if the 16-bit divider (`CX`) holds a value greater than the value in the 8-bit dividend (`BL`), the quotient from this integer division (`AX`) will always be zero. Not very spectacular!

The trick is to extend the dividend so we can use the word-sized division because that's the one that uses the desired 16-bit divider.

```
mov al, bl  ; \
mov ah, 0   ; / sets AX=BL
cwd         ; sets DX=0
div cx      ; divides DX:AX by CX producing quotient AX
```

As an alternative and provided that `CH` is zero:

```
mov al, bl  ; \
mov ah, 0   ; / sets AX=BL
div cl      ; divides AX by CL producing quotient AL
mov ah, 0   ; desired 16-bit quotient AX
```

**EDIT 2 after comment**

> AX is a 16 bit number...BL is the 8-bit number...Perform some instructions DIV BL.. AX is now the 16-bit quotient

If you absolutely want to perform `DIV BL`, it will always calculate `AX / BL` producing an 8-bit quotient in `AL` and an 8-bit remainder in `AH`. There's nothing you can do to change that.
Now, as you've said before, if you don't need that remainder and desire the quotient in the whole `AX` register, all you have to add is zeroing the `AH` register.

```
div bl
mov ah, 0   ; Quotient is now AX
```

Comment: [8086 assembly on DOSBox: Bug with idiv instruction?](//stackoverflow.com/a/43575674) shows the documentation for `div` and talks about 8-bit being the special case vs. DX:AX inputs/results for wider.

Comment: I'm sorry to be unclear...What I am actually trying to do is divide a 8 bit register by a 16-bit register in order to obtain a 16-bit quotient...i dont need the remainder

Comment: @MotherofStackoverflow See my amended answer.

Comment: AX is a 16 bit number...BL is the 8-bit number...Perform some instructions DIV BL.. AX is now the 16-bit quotient